# How to check sublink file is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I saved a file outside of rails projet and created sublink of that file in rails project but when I tried to check File.exists(sublink_file_path) it is returning false.

Eg:

```
 file_path = "shared/test.xls" #original file outside rails project.
 ln -nfs shared/test.xls current/tmp/test.xls #created a sublink in rails tmp folder. here current is my project folder.
```

Now fetching file path in controller like this

```
file_path = Rails.root + "tmp/test.xls"
File.exists?(file_path) #it return false but it should return true.
```

also check File.exist?(file_path) also return false.

How can I check sublink file is exist in ruby?

my directory structure:

```
 Work
   Project
     app
     config
     db
     tmp
     and so on...
  Shared
```

here project and shared in same level inside work folder. I am sure I am corrected with file path and directory structure. My concern is we can't check sublink path as file.

File.exist?(file_path) it will return true because file path is actual file path.

File.exist?(sublink_file_path)  I think sublink file path is not a file that's way it's returning false

Comment: `Rails.root` returns path **without** trailing slash. Try `Rails.root.join('tmp', 'test.xls')`

Comment: no,  its returing  #<Pathname:/root/work/project/tmp/test.xls> and also your code is returning false

Comment: Just do `Rails.root.to_s + "tmp/test.xls"`

Comment: @Arup it will remove trailing slash and will return work/projecttmp/test.xls it is not correct.

Comment: I know.. Just give how the file system looks like. Is `tmp`under `project` directory or outside?

Comment: Just noticed: did you missed `current` in front of `tmp`? `Rails.root.join('current', 'tmp', 'test.xls')` should do the trick.

Comment: where `current`belongs to ?

Comment: Project is my rails project and all things inside same as provided by rails. so tmp folder inside the project folder.

Comment: current = project folder

Comment: Just take snap of the directory structure and paste here. I think, path is not proper way is being created. We don't how directories are there..in your machines arranged.

Comment: Just write `File.exists?(file_path.to_s)`... I am sure it will work.If works... let me know. I will put it as answer.

Comment: I am sure my directory structure is correct there is no problem with my directory structure. my concern is when I tried to check sumlink path File.exist?(sublink_file_path) will return false because I think sublink_file_path is not a file.

Comment: @RamPatidar  Did you try, what I asked?

Comment: yes it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the problem of `File.exists?`, you just create a wrong symbolic link (*with wrong link path*).

Use the absolute path:

```
ln -nfs `pwd`/shared/test.xls current/tmp/test.xls
```

Or use the relative path:

```
ln -nfs ../../shared/test.xls current/tmp/test.xls
```

Then try again.

Comment: Also have tried symbolic link as you mentioned but File.exist?(symbolic_file_path) is returning false.  symbolic_file_path = "current/tmp/test.xls"  I have tried all possible area before post this question but somethings is wrong.

Comment: @RamPatidar What is the result of `file current/tmp/test.xls`?

Comment: Just created a symbolic link on local and check this symbolic file path using rails console and also it is returning false.

Comment: is your syntax correct? is returning  undefined local variable or method `file'

Comment: tmp/test.xls: broken symbolic link to `../shared/test.xls'

Comment: @RamPatidar You see, the symbolic link is broken, this is why `File.exist?` returns false.

Comment: Ok will look into it how to fix and thank you very much to share your time with me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have to set Absolute path in my case it is not working with relative path. I used :

```
ln -nsf /home/work/shared/test.xls /home/work/current/tmp/test.xls
```

check symbolic link is creating properly or not. Use below command

```
file "your_symbolic_link_path"
```

Now it is workign fine.